# How can I check how many times 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 appears in the input and put it in a list in Python?

Tags: python, counting

How can I check how many times `0` `1` `2` `3` `4` `5` `6` `7` `8` `9` appears in the input and put it in a list.

For example after someone inputs `122033`, the function should return the following list:

```
[1,1,2,2]
```

- `result[0]=1` means that 0 occurs 1 time
- `result[1]=1` means that 1 occurs 1 time
- `result[2]=2` means that 2 occurs 2 times
- `result[3]=2` means that 3 occurs 2 times

Please help I been stuck on how to do this for a day or two. It says I'm suppose to use result `= 10 * [0]`

Here is an example of an output

```
Enter a string of numbers: 4567899678
4 occurs 1 time
5 occurs 1 time
6 occurs 2 times
7 occurs 2 times
8 occurs 2 times
9 occurs 2 times
```

So far I tried this but I don't think that is how I'm suppose to do it.

```
def countdigits(aString):
    d = {}
    for i in aString:
        if i in d:
            d[i] = d[i]+1
        else:
            d[i] = 1
    return d
def main():
    aString=input("Enter numbers:")
    print(countdigits(aString))
main()
```

Comment: The answers provided are great. They do exactly what you want. If this is homework however, I don't think library solutions will be accepted. You will also not really learn anything.

Comment: Sorry, I know your answers are correct but I'm not really allowed to use collections yet because we are not that far ahead in our study. I'm suppose to use def countdigits(aString) and def main()  .Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @Jett please provide the code you've tried

Comment: I put the code I tried

Comment: i added a solution without using collections

Comment: If this is Python 2.x you should use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. Otherwise bad things could happen, given malicious user input.

Comment: Is ok. I'm using python 3 but thanks for reminding me :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> import collections
>>> a = collections.Counter([1,1,2,2])
>>> a
Counter({1: 2, 2: 2})
>>> a[1]
2 
>>> a[2]
2
>>>
```

if you are not supposed to use `collections`:

```
def count_digits(s):
    res = [0]*10
    for x in s:
        res[int(x)] += 1
    return res
```

Comment: This works thank you so much. I have another question if you don't mind. How can I remove the 0s. So that the list comes out [1,1,2,2] instead is coming out as [1, 1, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Answer (score 2):

Though your task is better solved using e.g. `Counter`, like other answers suggest, it does not conform to the hint of using `result = 10 * [0]`. Here's the intended solution:

```
def digit_count(number):
    # Make sure number is a string
    number = str(number)
    counts = [0] * 10
    for digit in number:
        counts[int(digit)] += 1
    return counts

counts = digit_count(122033)

for digit, count in enumerate(counts):
    if count == 0:
        continue
    print "{0} occurs {1} time{2}".format(
        digit, count, "" if count == 1 else "s")
```

Note that `digit_count` only accepts an positive integer or a string of digits. It raises a ValueError if you supply a negative number, a float or a complex number.

Comment: I think this probably fits in the assignment - although I believe the OP was on a better track using a `dict` if the end result is filtering out empty occurrences anyway... Anyway - breaking is good in this case - as it means it's a non-digit - I would consider that desired behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

remove the zeros :

```
def count_digits(s):
    res = [0]*10
    for x in s:
        res[int(x)] += 1
    while 0 in res:
        re.remove(0)
    return res
```